# How to configure postfix with ufw so that my web server can send email but it doesn't act as an open relay?

Tags: smtp, email-server, ubuntu-14.04, ufw

According to [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04):

> It is important to secure your server and make sure that Postfix is not configured as an open relay.

It links to [another guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-securing-your-linux-vps) which suggests using UFW as a firewall.

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu with a PHP application that needs to send email. I've installed postfix as my mail server.

I've configured UFW so far with:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow www
```

To allow email out, would I tell UFW to allow smtp?:

```
sudo ufw allow smtp
```

Is there anything else I need to do to allow email to be sent out?

Answer (score 5):

Don't open your servers smtp port to the world. [php](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) should be sending mail using `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.

If you need to send out using a remote server, [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/40478/how-to-configure-php-ini-with-remote-smtp) may be of interest.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The sendmail command is provided by postfix. However how does sendmail/postfix send the email off the server if it doesn't use smtp?

Comment: Postfix does use smtp for this, but it does so as a client. This doesn't require exposing a server port. If you can apt-get or curl without issue, postfix should be able to send mail, at least as far as iptables/ufw is concerned.